# Sharepoint Beginner Questions: where to store data?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm about to develop an application in Sharepoint.
I've got experience in asp.net and C#, Domino, Java, etc..

Now my 1000$ question: Where can I store data in Sharepoint? I'm aware there are list definitions.. so is it a good practice to store the data "natively" in Sharepoint using lists, or traditionally in an external data container, e.g. ms sql 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Because SharePoint is essentially a .NET Web Application, the options are virtually limitless for how you store data used in your application. The two most common practices would be to use SharePoint lists to store your data, or to store the data in a SQL database.

I would suggest that each have their advantages. A SharePoint list is advantageous because it can be seen by the users and you can leverage out of the box features to allow users to do CRUD operations. A SQL database makes more sense when the size of the data is large and does not fit well within the constructs of the SharePoint lists. SQL is going to perform much faster when doing bulk operations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.. meanwhile i've found also an interesting page: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647105.aspx)